# problem dealing with request parameter using jsp within a javascript block

Tags: javascript, jsp

I've a jsp page which saves a request parameter inside a javascript variable. Say a user visits the page through a wish list then the param fromWishList is set to 1, if the user visits this page from other source then there is no param called fromWishList.

```
//following code is inside a jsp page
<script type="text/javascript">
  var isWishList = '<c:out value="${param.fromWishList}" />';
    if(isWishList != ''){
      //page visited via wishList
    } else {
      //page visited via other sources
    }
</script>
```

Now my problem is that if a user visits the page via wish list the javascript var isWishList is set permanently set to '1', so that if the same user visits the page again via other sources the isWishList is still set to '1'. In the second case i wanted it to be blank.

I'm struggling with this since long time. I appreciate any help.

Comment: This much sounds like you're using old fashioned HTML `<frameset>`. Is this true? If not, then posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (short, self contained, compileable and executable code snippet) would help a lot.

Comment: how can the javascript be set permanently to 1? Is it not set to whatever the JSP contains?

Anyway you can choose not to show the script at all if the param is set, just wrap the script in a <c:if></c:if>

Comment: @BalusC 

No, we are not using any <frameset> .

Comment: Then post an SSCCE. The above code/information gives us nothing to work with. It all looks fine. It is either you're not running the code you think you're running, or the URL **actually** contains the query parameter or you're using a frameset wherein the frame's URL (invisibly) contains the parameter.

Comment: @BalusC, @mplungjan,  What i feel like is that once the server generates the html page by parsing the jsp, the values are hardcoded into the html. Now even if the user visits the jsp page again the previously generated html is being served by the server. Is this the case ?

Comment: No, @Raja, that is not the case. The HTML is regenerated for each request.

Comment: You should be able to use your browser debugger to look at what the page actually contains. It may be that there is some other problem causing incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to take a look at the generated html code in your browser to see what values in both cases are assigned to the isWishList variable.
You check for the empty string ''. You might better check for the string '1' because in the other case the value might be something like 'null' or similar. Don't know what jsp renders in this case.